# firebase deploy skips exported function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I recently added a new cloud function to my project, and for some reason when I deploy it gets skipped:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:stripeOperation
```

which results in

> ⚠  functions: the following filters were specified but do not match
>   any functions in the project: stripeOperation

The file structure is like this:

```
functions/
├── src/
│   ├── stripe
│   │    ├── index.ts
│   │    ├── myTrigger.ts
│   │    ├── anotherTrigger.ts
│   │    └── stripeOperation.ts
│   ├── index.ts
```

`functions/src/stripe/index` exports all 3 of the functions in the stripe folder.
`functions/src/index` exports them from the stripe folder:

```
export { stripeOperation, myTrigger, anotherTrigger } from './stripe';
```

Here's where it gets weird - `myTrigger` and `anotherTrigger` successfully deploy, but `stripeOperation` doesn't. There are no build errors. Firebase isn't giving me any clues as to why it's skipped. I checked and the transpiled code looks fine. `stripeOperation` is a callable function but the other 2 are firestore triggers. This is the signature of `stripeOperation`:

```
export const stripeOperation = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  ...
});
```

Is there any way to determine why firebase won't deploy my function? I am using `"firebase-functions": "^2.3.1"`

**Update:** I have tried renaming the function, and completely switching out the function body with a previously deployed function, and neither worked.

Comment: Can you add the signature of `stripeOperation` to the question too? I doubt it'll be really different, but want to make sure.

Comment: I updated my example to include the signature of `stripeOperation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export callable functions separately from trigger functions. This doesn't make sense, so I [filed an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1357).

`functions/src/index`:

```
export { stripeOperation } from './stripe/stripeOperation';
export { myTrigger, anotherTrigger } from './stripe';
```